# rolling three day average in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find three day average of values. Expected output:

| dt | amt | running_avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-1 | 100 | 0 |
| 2022-05-2 | 150 | 0 |
| 2022-05-3 | 50 | 100 |
| 2022-05-14 | 250 | 150 |
| 2022-05-15 | 0 | 100 |

Average should be calculated for 3 day window. My query is:

```
select a.dt, avg(b.amt) over(order by a.dt ) as running_avg,b.amt
from trans a
left join trans b on b.dt = a.dt
where a.dt between DATEADD(day,-3, a.dt) and getdate()
```

My query is just giving normal running average and not average for 3 days. Let me know how this can be done in SQL Server.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have `0`s for `running_avg` for the first two rows? Maybe you need the `ROWS/RANGE` argument in the windowed `AVG()`.

Comment: i want to add 0 for first 2 rows bcoz it want it to calculate average from 3rd row as it is a 3 day running average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need a `ROWS/RANGE` argument in the windowed `AVG()`:

Data:

```
SELECT *
INTO trans
FROM (VALUES
   (CONVERT(date, '20220501'), 100),
   (CONVERT(date, '20220502'), 150),
   (CONVERT(date, '20220503'), 50),
   (CONVERT(date, '20220514'), 250),
   (CONVERT(date, '20220515'), 0)
) v (dt, amt)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   dt, 
   amt,
   AVG(amt) OVER (ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_avg,
   CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) = 3 
      THEN AVG(amt) OVER (ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
      ELSE 0
   END AS running_avg2
FROM trans
ORDER BY dt
```

Results:

| dt | amt | running_avg | running_avg2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 100 | 100 | 0 |
| 2022-05-02 | 150 | 125 | 0 |
| 2022-05-03 | 50 | 100 | 100 |
| 2022-05-14 | 250 | 150 | 150 |
| 2022-05-15 | 0 | 100 | 100 |